# Best way to have a variable template in php

Tags: php, html

I'm coding a menu bar for a website in php. Because I don't want to have to edit it multiple times on the half a dozen or so pages I'll have I've decided to put it in it's own separate `header.php` file and just `include_once(header.php)` in the various pages.

My problem is that the menu is going to be slightly different depending on which page it's included in. Right now I'm dealing with it by having the following in my `header.php` file with `$PageTitle` being defined in the individual pages:

```
if ($PageTitle == "Home"){
    echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>';
}
else{
    echo '<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>';
}
if ($PageTitle == "About"){
    echo '<li class="active"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>';
}
else{
    echo '<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>';
}
...
```

The `active` class simply highlights the menu of the current page (Like the menu bar on the top of StackOverflow). It works fine but I'm curious if there is a better perhaps more efficient way to doing this. Thanks guys.

Comment: use a ternary and don't put every option in a conditional... `echo '<li '. ($PageTitle == "Home" ? "class=\"active\"" : ""); .'><a href="#">Home</a></li>';`

Comment: You might also want to configure your menu links in an `array` and then use a `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//list of menu headers

$headers = new array();

//populate the array with your headers here ...

foreach($headers as $val)
{
     if( $PageTitle == $val )
         echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$val.'</a></li>';
     else
         echo '<li><a href="#">'.$val.'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for current class you can also use jquery if you want to:

```
$(function(){
    var path = location.href;
    if ( path )
    $('.side_menu a[href="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'current');
});
```